# How to properly provide data to update function?

Tags: r, model, regression

Let's consider function following which performs logit or probit regression:

```
my_glm <- function(y, x, model_type = "logit") {
  do.call("glm", c(list(
    formula = y ~ ., data = base::quote(as.data.frame(x)),
    family = quote(binomial(link = model_type))
  )))
}
```

(I know this function is build in very strange way, but it takes very important role in part of my bigger function)

Now let's fit a model using artificial data and function `my_glm`:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- sample(0:1, 100, T)
df <- data.frame("Exp" = rexp(100), "Norm" = rnorm(100))
my_model <- my_glm(y, df)
```

What I want to have is a function which performs likelihood ratio test on model from function `my_model`.

**My work so far**

Because my function `my_glm` is created using `do.call` function I can't just code this function as:

```
#Incorrect!

library(lmtest)
test_model <- function(model) {  
   lrtest(model)
}
```

I have to use function `update`. So it's very straightforward to do it on the link function:

```
# Link function correct
# Problem: Missing data

library(lmtest)
test_model <- function(model) {
  if (model$family$link == "logit") {
    test <- lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("logit")))
  }
  else if (model$family$link == "probit") {
    test <- lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("probit")))
  }
  test
}
```

However still I don't know how to update my model by data. I tried to replace

```
test <- lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("logit")))
```

by

```
test <- lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("logit"), data = model$model[-1]))
```

But it's not working. Is there any way how can I update this model correctly so that `lrtest` can be performed?

**EDIT**

Current code after nicola's comments:

```
test_model <- function(model) {
  if (model$family$link == "logit") {
    test <- lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("logit"), data = model$model[-1]))
  }
  else if (model$family$link == "probit") {
    test <- lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("probit"), data = model$model[-1]))
  }
  test
}
```

When trying to run it on `my_model`:

```
test_model(my_model)
```

I get error:

```
Error: node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow
```

Another try (simpler one):

```
test_model <- function(model) {
    test <- lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("logit"), data = model$model[-1]))
}

test_model(my_model)

 Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'model' not found
```

Comment: Try `update(model, family = binomial("logit"), data = model$model[-1])`. The argument is called `data` and `x` was the value in the call.

Comment: Hey @nicola thank you very much for your answer! You are right, it's reasonable to replace it, but `lrtest(update(model, family = binomial("logit"), data = model$model[-1]))` gives exactly same result.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are running and the error received, just to be on the same page. You are just defining functions, so it is left to reader to understand what does not work.